# How to allow calls to Cognito from an AWS ECS container instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cognito, aws-fargate

I have a setup with an ALB and a target group created by ECS, I'm using Fargate and created a build pipeline by following [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html#pipeline-wizard). My app is built with NET core, I have an Angular frontend. Got all this working, I'm able to deploy my code changes, but I'm a bit stuck with the following issue.

I'm using Cognito for authentication and a custom domain that I set for the hosted UI. It seems that, from the browser, when I try to hit an endpoint that is secured, I get a 504 Gateway error, which somehow is not doing the redirect to Cognito in the browser. All this works fine when I run the application on localhost.

When I looked at the logs, I noticed the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<region_and_a_code>/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

Apparently, it can't establish a connection to Cognito. My containers are using only port 80, my target group instances are also using port 80, ALB uses HTTPS on 443 which directs the traffic to the target group, and for ALB port 80 I just redirect to 443.

I tried a few different things, like setting the authority value instead of the metadata address, tried using a BackChannelHttpHandler to execute the HTTPS call, tried updating the port mappings to allow communication on 443, but somehow it seems that it gets overridden by the task definition that I have created when I set up the build pipeline. The network mode in my task definition is now awsvpc, and if I try to set it to host, it will complain that I can't use it with Fargate.

What do I need to do to allow the HTTPS request from my Docker container instances to reach Cognito?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set this up in a public ALB.  This setup using a private NLB will work, might work with a private ALB as well.  You can then set up vmc private links to get at the service's you need access too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).